# how to display author name in custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, author

What should write for display_name?
I want to display author name in custom post types, but I got administrater name ‘root’ for get_the_author() function and when I used get_the_auther_meta(), I couldn’t get anything.
If anyone knows please let me know.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What I did wrong is, I forget to get author box, hence the_author function was not working, so I add this code in functions.php file

```
    add_post_type_support( 'my_post_type', array(
    'author', 'excerpt',
    ) );
```

then I got author box and in author box, set author name and add this code in custom post file

```
   the_author();
```

or

```
    echo get_the_author_meta('display_name');
```